# Batch removal unwanted legend entries in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, batch, charts

I have a lot of series in my chart legend, but I just need just a few of them.

[image]

I bounded with black just these series which I need. The rest of them should be deleted.

I know how to delete the series, but just one by one. I tried to find something, which would allow me to delete more than one entry. I just found some VBA Excel options, which show how to categorize these entries and remove them.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56223026/how-to-delete-only-extra-legend-entries-that-are-not-needed-in-a-stacked-bar-cha

but it doesn't help really.

Is there any way of batch removing unwanted data series in Excel charts?

Comment: do you need to delete only the legend of the series, or the whole series? which type of chart do you use?

Comment: This is a scatter chart. I would like to delete the legend of the series.